# Why does wheat consume more water than rice that is, unlike wheat, flooded?

Tags: botany, agriculture

Why does wheat consume [more](https://www.waterfootprint.org/media/downloads/Report47-WaterFootprintCrops-Vol1.pdf) water than rice that is, unlike wheat, flooded? I thought rice was the villain of the piece when it comes to water consumption.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. In addition, you should not expect other users to follow links or search for information in multipage ...

Comment: ... documents. Instead, quote or summarize the relevant information (with references).  ——— Also be aware that this is not a forum or tutorial service; it is a Q&A site where *specific* questions relating to biology get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask] a good question.